# Force URL of local blobstore response

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using facebook login on my site.  When I test locally I need to use `local.mysite.com`, so facebook thinks the request is coming from my site.  This works great except when I upload images to blobstore.  When uploading images app engine always switches to `localhost:888`.  This makes the browser think cross site scripting is happening and prevents my uploads.  How can I force app engine to use `local.mysite.com` instead of `localhost:888`

This is the error I am getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/_ah/upload/agpidWJwcm9qZWN0chsLEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YBQw. Origin http://local.mysite.com:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can actually change that URL.

What you can do though is to use the `localhost:8888` for your local tests and create another Facebook application that points to localhost. Afterwards there are two approaches that you can do in order be able to use these two (or possibly even more in the future) Facebook applications in your app.

- You can decided based on the requested URL which key to use
- Store all the keys in somekind configuration Datatstore that only admins can change them

With the first approach you will have to store somehow all the keys in your code or even worse in the datastore and then decided based on the URL which one to use. This approach is not good and it doesn't scale very well. The second approach is preferable since you don't have to store your keys in the code, it is more secure and it scales much better since you don't need to know up front how many different Facebook applications you have.

You can read the [Nick Johnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3778576/8418) on how to solve that in Python, but the idea is Java so it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I've had problems using localhost as a facebook domain.  Facebook thinks we are trying to load facebook resources and blocks a lot of actions.

Comment: @Lumpy Weird.. I never had any issues by adding the http://localhost:8080 on Facebook to be able to test locally my logins. Maybe they changed something recently.. either case it's a good idea to store your configuration properties in datastore instead of the code.