# What to consider opensourcing a Google Appengine application

Tags: google-app-engine, open-source

We've made this monitoring tool at our company.
It's not in our line of business so we might as well opensource the tool, and maybe someone else likes it as well, maybe they'll contribute.

The tool runs on AppEngine, so there are so the are some paths in the appengine configuration, that might be a good idea to keep hidden. Unless someone else wants to start using our appengine qouta.

Is there a best practice for open-sourcing AppEngine applications?
Does anyone have any experience to share regarding opensourcing appengine sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some ideas from excellent [gae-init](https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init). The way its working in order to avoid exposing sensitive information, is moving it in a stand alone project, you can even use gae-init for that ;)

As part of the model is a Config class which holds all the information as it concerns the service and its dependencies. There are some default values there but it can also be easily customized from a web interface called admin. Have a look.

Comment: You could check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3778576/8418 on how to store sensitive data in Datastore and from the same answer you can find other methods. While Nick's answer is using `db` if you are using `ndb` the caching is done automatically for you so there is no need to store in a variable.. (https://github.com/gae-init/gae-init/blob/master/main/modelx.py#L33)