# Set environment variables in GAE control panel

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I deploy my project to GAE over Github. There is some foreign API-key which I don't want to save in repository and make them public. Is it possible to set an environment variable for a project in GAE control panel so I can catch it in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define environment variables in configuration file for App Engine application. In case of Python, it is `app.yaml`

```
env_variables:
   MY_ENV_VAR: 'some_value'
```

You can find more details [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables).

There is no such a thing like project parameters that can be defined in Developers Console at the moment.

Comment: yes, but I don't want to add private API key in a file which will be committed in the repo by Github.

Comment: It is definitely valid, however, I am afraid that there is no such a thing like project parameters that can be defined in Developers Console.

Comment: Sad, heroku have something like this `heroku config:add KEY1=foobar KEY2=frobozz
`

Answer (score 4):

You can store your keys in datastore. Later when you need them in the code, you can fetch them from datastore and cache them by memcache.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using the Datastore for keys like this. See the code in my answer at [Securely storing environment variables in GAE with app.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669528/securely-storing-environment-variables-in-gae-with-app-yaml/35261091#35261091)

That code auto-generates placeholder values that you can then update from the developer console. Also, it uses the ndb library, so reading the keys is fast.