# Google App Engine: How to define secret system properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I am deploying a SpringBoot application to GAE and want to set some system properties to be used in my `application.yml` file. Other cloud providers like Azure or Heroku allow me to define system properties for each application but I can't find out how to do this in GAE. I don't want the values in source control since they contain passwords.

What I want to do specifically:

- Add a system property `MONGODB_URI` somewhere on GAE
- Reference it in `application.yml` like so: `MONGODB_URI: ${MONGODB_URI}`

This seems like a pretty standard use case to me but I can't find anything  (satisfying) about it. These questions regard the same matter:

- [Securely storing environment variables in GAE with app.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669528/securely-storing-environment-variables-in-gae-with-app-yaml)
- [Set environment variables in GAE control panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673772/set-environment-variables-in-gae-control-panel/35254560#35254560)

I understand I can create entities and access them through an api in the code. But it bothers me that I need to make code changes for a simple use case like this, and it should be possible to pass some secret environment properties to the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables to the Java 8 App Engine standard environment by [addind them in the `appengine-web.xml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#env_variables).

```
<env-variables>
  <env-var name="MONGODB_URI" value="MONGODB_URI_VALUE" />
</env-variables>
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want have your keys harcoded in your source code nor in your App Engine config files, the recommended approach is to store secrets in Google Cloud Platform using [Cloud Key Management Service](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/) and [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/store-secrets).

Comment: should have made this clearer in my question, but the point is I don't want to have the value in source control (thus "secret" environment variables)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have updated my answer.