# How to set environment variables/app secrets in Google App Engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The question is **how can I set application secrets to make them available in `application.yml`**?

On heroku I was doing it simply, by setting environment variable for dyno, and acces it as:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT}
security:
  user:
    password: ${USERPASSWORD}

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    securePortEnabled: true
  password: ${EUREKAPASSWORD}
```

How to achieve that in Google App Engine? I was trying with `datastore`:
[image]

Unfornately I don't know how to inject those values into my *.yml file.

EDIT:

One more important thing to add. I am using `maven appengine` plugin to deploy my app via CI pipeline, so there is no possibility for me to push `app.yaml` file to App Engine

Comment: By `*.yml` are you referring to the GAE services' `.yaml` configuration files used by the GAE infra itself? Or some other `.yml` files that *your app* reads *after* it is launched in order to perform some functionality?

Comment: Hello. I am using maven appengine plugin, so I don't push app.yaml file to Google. Even if I would do that, variable kept in such file is not secert :). I have editet my question accordingly.

Comment: As I said, if I will store password in file, it is no longer secret. From the other side: here you got something about appengine plugin: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how you want to *use* that secret info, which IMHO is essential to be able to comment on the method of *storing* it. You need to clarify that. What exactly is that `application.yml` you mentioned?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html  `application.yml` is configuration file for spring-boot application. In that file I am can specify under which environment variable, app should look for given value (IE: ${somePassword}). The value of  `somePassword` I want to set up on GAE to **do not store it in repository or any local file**.

Comment: I am looking for explanation how to achieve, something what is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25174905/2849613

Comment: Yup, I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store secrets that are available to the app at runtime, keeping them in the datastore isn't a bad idea. I know of many apps that do that.

Here's an [app used by the Khan Academy](https://github.com/Khan/snippets) that's a good example of storing secret credentials in the datastore. It's in Python, but you can get the general idea. Note that on [first admin login](https://github.com/Khan/snippets/blob/master/snippets.py#L182), it prompts for secrets to store.

Answer (score 1):

Google has also a tutorial on how to store encrypted secrets.
https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/store-secrets

TLDR: a separate bucket to store the encrypted secrets, instances download it when needed, decrypt using Google KMS (https://cloud.google.com/kms/) and remove afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The best and secure way is to use GCP KMS or some third party secrets manager product like [vault](https://www.hashicorp.com/products/vault/).

**GCP KMS**

1. We need to use a service account with encrypt and decrypt permission(role) to encrypt the credentials(secrets) file.
2. Upload the encrypted credential file to GCS
3. Fetch the encrypted credential from GCS and decrypt and parse it(E.g. parse to plain java object) at runtime in your application code.

**Datastore**

Yes. We can store credentials/secrets environment variables into datastore and fetch them at runtime in application code.

Pros:

1. Simple
2. It can be used almost everywhere, GAE standard environment, GAE flexible environment, GCE, GCF, GKE, Cloud Run.

Cons:

1. Security is not as good as KMS.

**GCE metadata**

I used to use GCE metadata server to store my secret environment variables.

Pros:

1. It supports GAE, GCE, GKE.
2. Very simple. We just need to send HTTP requests to `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/` endpoint to fetch our custom metadatas(the secrets environment variables).

Cons:

1. Last year, GCE metadata doesn't support Cloud Function. (runtime: nodejs10).I can't fetch my custom secrets environment variables from GCE metadata within cloud function. But built-in metadatas can be fetched, like `projectId`.
2. security is not as good as KMS.

**configmap and secrets(Only for GKE)**

Simple base64 encryption is possible. Medium difficulty to use. Security is not as good as KMS.

**Another hack way**

I also create a post for this question here: [How to pass system environment variables to app.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139716/how-to-pass-system-environment-variables-to-app-yaml)

Yes, the Linux script way can do everything. But I don't like these hack way.

Comment: Google now has something (in Beta) called Secret Manager: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs