# How to set environment variables using Google Cloud Build or other method in Google App Engine Standard Environment?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Is there anyway to inject environment variables from Cloud Build into the App Engine Standard environment?

I do not want to push my environment variables to GitHub inside the `app.yaml` or `.env`. Thus, when Cloud Build pulls and deploys it is missing the `.env` file and the server is unable to complete some requests.

I am trying to avoid using Datastore as the async nature of Datastore will make the code a lot more messy. I tried to use encrypted secrets found [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials), but that doesn't seem to work as I added the secrets to app deploy and they do not make their way into the deployment, so I assume this is not the use case for Cloud Build.

I also tried the tutorial [here](http://gunargessner.com/gcloud-env-vars/), to import the `.env` file into App Engine Standard from storage, but since Standard does not have local storage I assume it goes into the void.

So is there anyway to inject the `.env` into App Engine Standard environment without using Datastore, or committing `app.yaml` or `.env` to change control? Potentially using Cloud Build, KMS, or some type of storage?

Here is what I tried for `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
  secretEnv: ['SECRET1', 'SECRET2', 'SECRET3', 'SECRET4', 'SECRET5']
timeout: "1600s"

secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/<Project-Name>/locations/global/keyRings/<Key-Ring-Name>/cryptoKeys/<Key-Name>
  secretEnv:
    SECRET1: <encrypted-key-base64 here>
    SECRET2: <encrypted-key-base64 here>
    SECRET3: <encrypted-key-base64 here> 
    SECRET4: <encrypted-key-base64 here> 
    SECRET5: <encrypted-key-base64 here>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@brian.young.pro/how-to-add-environmental-variables-to-google-app-engine-node-js-using-cloud-build-5ce31ee63d7) on how to securely store env vars in your cloud build (triggers) settings and import them into your app.

Basically there are three steps:

1. Add your env vars to the 'variables' section in one of your build trigger settings

   [Screenshot of where to add variables in build triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgRiE.png)

   By convention variables set in the build trigger must begin with an underscore (_)
2. Configure `cloudbuild.yaml` (on the second step in the code example) to read in variables from your build trigger, set them as env vars, and write all env vars in a local .env file

   Add `couldbuild.yaml` (below) to your project root directory

```js
steps:
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["install"]
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["run", "create-env"]
  env:
    - 'MY_SECRET_KEY=${_MY_SECRET_KEY}'
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

Add `create-env` script to `package.json`

```js
"scripts": {
  "create-env": "printenv > .env"
},
```

3. Read env vars from .env to your app (config.js)

   Install dotenv package

   `npm i dotenv -S`

   Add a `config.js` to your app

```js
// Import all env vars from .env file
require('dotenv').config()

export const MY_SECRET_KEY = process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY

console.log(MY_SECRET_KEY) // => Hello
```

Done! Now you may deploy your app by triggering the cloud build and your app will have access to the env vars.

Comment: Worked fantastic! Thank you! Also your article was great to follow along with. You're a real hero.

Comment: @AlexSupkay Glad you liked the solution. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I am trying this solution but the substitute var in the .env file in gcloud is empty. Any idea ?

Comment: I had problems with this solution but it was because I did not understand the steps well, in step 2 I did not understand that I had to manually edit the package.json file and add the sentence "" create-env ":" printenv> .env "" after doing this correctly, it worked perfect.

Comment: Looks like this solution doesn't work anymore. Had issues as other commenters on Medium. Ended up using CloudBuild trigger variables and separate app.yaml files

Comment: Great. Thanks you!

Comment: Can you bake the .env file into the image?

Comment: i didn't need the config.js step.  otherwise worked great!

Comment: No need to do all the stuff involving npm - you can just make your build step say:
- name: "bash" \n
  script: "echo MY_SECRET_KEY=${_MY_SECRET_KEY} > .env"

Comment: Hate how stack overflow doesn't allow newlines... you get what i've done though hopefully

Answer (score 3):

I have another solution, if someone is still interested in this. This should work on all languages, because environment variables are added directly into `app.yaml` file

1. Add substitution variable in build trigger (as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56815454/5665606)).
2. Add environment variables to `app.yaml` in a way they can be easily substituted with build trigger variables. Like this:

```
    env_variables:
     SECRET_KEY: %SECRET_KEY%
```

3. Add a step in `cloudbuild.yaml` to substitute all `%XXX%` variables inside `app.yaml` with their values from build trigger.

```
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
      entrypoint: bash
      args:
      - '-c'
      - |
      sed -i 's/%SECRET_KEY%/'${_SECRET_KEY}'/g' app.yaml
      gcloud app deploy  app.yaml
```

Comment: weird, I am getting a no such file while running this sed -i 's/%SECRET_KEY%/'${_SECRET_KEY}'/g' app.yaml

Comment: The point of injecting these variables during build is having the secrets in a location with more restricted access than the code base. 
app.yaml is (and should be; as it serves other purposes than isolating the secrets) within the codebase.

Answer (score 3):

You should NOT <sup>**NOT AT ALL** <sup>***please!***</sup></sup> store secrets within any configuration store that keeps values in plain text. These types of security blunders are not acceptable in 2023, even for toy projects.

Config stores that keep plain text values are intended for storing things that are NOT secrets but values that are used in many places and are better off not repeated.

There is a reason, therefore, these stores have a word "variable" in their name, and not "secret".

```
Cloud Build
```

[image]

```
Github
```

[image]

All the build systems (should) come with two types of stores - one that keeps plain text values and other that stores encrypted secrets.

Cloud Build has secrets manager and Github has secrets. Use them for storing your tokens, keys, etc.

Check this out for Cloud Build - https://timothyreynolds.co.uk/words/2019/securing-environment-variables-in-google-cloud-build

Once you get your secrets from secrets manager, then you can do what other answers here are doing. But the source of the secrets should not be the plaintext config store.

Comment: this is also an excellent resource using the same approach:  https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets

Answer (score 0):

Based on your preferences that you have highlighted (Cloud Build, KMS). The Google Secrets link that you had mentioned involves storing sensitive data at build or runtime using [Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/secret-management%60%60): KeyRing and CryptoKey. However, Google offers other Secret Management Solutions using Cloud KMS as well.

Here are a couple of other options you can use while [storing Secrets](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/store-secrets%60%60):

**Option 1** : You can store **Secrets in code** that are encrypted **with a key from Cloud KMS.**
(This is typically used by encrypting your secret at the application layer.)

*Benefit:* Provides a layer of **security** from insider threats because it **restricts access** to the code **with a corresponding key**.

*[You can find some additional information about these options on the Google Documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/secret-management%60%60).]*

**Option 2:** You can **Store Secrets** inside a Google Storage **[Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets%60%60)** where your data is at **[rest encryption.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_at_rest%60%60)** (Similar to option 1 this has the ability to limit access to secrets to a small group of Developers.)

*Benefit:* Storing your secrets in a **separate location** ensures that **if a breach** of your code repository has **occurred**,  your secrets **may still be protected**.)

*[Note: Google recommends that you use two projects for proper [separation of duties](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/separation-of-duties%60%60). One project will use Cloud KMS to manage the keys and the other project will use Cloud Storage to store the secrets.]*

If the options listed above still do not meet your needs, I have found a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669528/securely-storing-environment-variables-in-gae-with-app-yaml%60%60) that shares a similar objective as your project. (i.e: Storing environment variables in GAE **without** Datastore)

The solution provided on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669528/securely-storing-environment-variables-in-gae-with-app-yaml%60%60) illustrates the use of storing keys in a client_secrets.json file that gets excluded when uploading to git by listing it in .gitignore. You can find some **Google** **examples** (Python) of [usage here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets%60%60).

Comment: I feel like this is a generic copy-pasta type answer that doesn't address the specific question as it applies to multiple-environment settings, using Node

Answer (score 0):

The highfivebrian [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56815454/7460038) is great, but I'm adding my slightly different solution.

**1).** In the root project folder we need the cloudbuild.yaml file but I'll call it `buildsetttings.yaml`, because
first one name have a [problem](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/397)

In buildsetttings.yaml I added this code:

```js
    steps:
  - name: node
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ['install']
  - name: node
    entrypoint: npm
    env:
      - 'DB_URL=${_DB_URL}'
      - 'SENDGRID_API_KEY=${_SENDGRID_API_KEY}'
      - 'CLIENT_ID=${_CLIENT_ID}'
    args: ['run', 'create-app-yaml']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy']
```

buildsetttings.yaml will be create app.yaml file in the Cloud Build, using a npm `create-app-yaml` command.
**Tip:** app.yaml file we will then use to deploy our app to GCP App Engine.

**2).** In the root folder(near buildsetttings.yaml) we need to create `create-app-yaml.js` which will run in Cloud Build after it is called from buildsetttings.yaml.

In buildsetttings.yaml I added this code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const fs = require('fs');

const appYamlContent = `runtime: nodejs14
env_variables:
  DB_URL: ${process.env.DB_URL}
  SENDGRID_API_KEY: ${process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY}
  CLIENT_ID: ${process.env.CLIENT_ID}`;

fs.writeFileSync('./app.yaml', appYamlContent);
```

This code using a npm package `dotenv`(add it to package.json) and get variables from Cloud Build Trigger Variables and create with they app.yaml file.

**3).** app.yaml file was created in the Cloud build and our last step(name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud') in the buildsetttings.yaml, using app.yaml file, deploy the project to the Google Cloud App Engine.

**Success!**

**In short, it works like this**: buildsetttings.yaml run "create-app-yaml.js" in the Cloud Build, after which dynamically creates an app.yaml file by adding variables from Cloud Build Trigger Variables, then makes a deployment in the App Engine.

**Notes:**

- Delete the file app.yamlin from you project, because it will be create dynamically in the Cloud Build. Also delete cloudbuild.yaml file, because instead we use buildsetttings.yaml.
- package.json:

[image: code]

- Cloud Build Trigger Variables:

[image: GCP Build cloud nodejs]

Answer (score 0):

As of `2020/11/13`. It seem like `.env` will work only at that step and in the next step an invisible `.env` will no longer there.

If you get stuck do try consume that printed `.env` it in 1 step like this ...
in `cloudbuild.yaml`

```yaml
# [START cloudbuild_yarn_node]
steps:
  # Install
  - name: node
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ["install"]
  # Build
  - name: node
    entrypoint: yarn
    env:
      - "FOO=${_FOO}"
    args: ["env-build"]
```

and in `package.json` add this

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "env-build": "printenv > .env && yarn build",
  }
}
```

in `index.js`

```js
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.FOO);
```

Took me an hour to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

First, I created secret using gcp secret manager and uploaded my env file there.
Second, I called the secret in cloudbuild.yaml on run time and created a file with name of '.env' using echo.

Example

```
steps: 
- id: "Injecting ENV"
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        echo $$ENV > .env
  secretEnv: ['ENV']


availableSecrets: 
  - versionName: projects/<Project-Name>/secrets/environment-variables/versions/1
    env: 'ENV'
timeout: 900s
```