# Secret environment variables in Cloudbuild (with out files), how?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-build

I am creating a CI/CD pipeline in Cloud Build of a very basic Node.js app with deployment to GCP appengine standard.

None-secret environment variables are stored in `app.yaml` file. But of course I don't want to put my secrets there. In fact I don't want to put them in any file any where (encrypted or not) since this file will end up on the AppEngine instance and can be "viewed" by a "bad admin". There are many samples out there that suggests to encrypt/decrypt complete files (and some times even code) but I don't want to go down that path.

I am looking for a way to set secret environment variables "in memory" as part of the CI/CD pipeline.  Anyone?

I added none secrets in the `app.yaml` file (env_variables) - works fine
Added encrypted secrets into my `cloudbuild.yaml` file (secrets) - no error
Added secretEnv: into a build steps but value don't end up as process.env.[KEY] in app engine

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
  dir: "appengine/hello-world/standard"
 - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "test-app.yaml"]
  dir: "appengine/hello-world/standard"
  secretEnv: ['API_KEY', 'API_URL']

secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/XXXXXXXX/locations/global/keyRings/customintegrations-secrets/cryptoKeys/integration-secrets
  secretEnv:
    API_KEY: XXQAoHgKKoHBKOURrUU2RqU+ki8XyqmTjz+ns+MEWp5Kx3hQBpgSQgATFQ5yRdW4m1TLNqNRIdHIqVJi8tn8jFrtlHIEouOzNDe/ASlOT0ZQBfl9Rf7xlvOHAa667poBq2hEoMNvOclxUQ==
    API_URL: YYQAoHgKKklo08ZsQF+/8M2bmi9nhWEtb6klyY4rNthUhSIhQ8oSQQATFQ5ywKOxaM/TLwGDmvMtCpl/1stXOOK0kgy42yipYbw/J/QZL68bMat1u4H3Hvp/GMbUVIKEb9jwUtN2xvbL
```

I was hoping that the `secretEnv: ['API_KEY', 'API_URL']` would make the decrypted values accessable in code (`process.env.API_KEY`) in app engine.

Comment: I have been wanting to do the same but the only way I found was to encrypt a file in Cloud Storage with a KMS the Cloud Build Service Account has access to and download+decrypt. This in order to centralize (to some extent) the secrets.

Comment: Thanks. How did you get the values in the file into env variables so you could access them in code like, process.env.API_KEY?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#encrypting_a_file_using_the_cryptokey) explains the process, so once the file is decrypted during the build step you should be able to reference it as normal.

Comment: @CorinneWhite the document you refer to doesn’t put the secretEnv: ['API_KEY', 'API_URL'] decrypted values as ENV variables. I have already tried this. Are you telling me that there is absolutely no way I can achieve what I need. I.e. secrets in ENV variables with NO file containing the secrets in clear-text deployed to GAE.(read above for the details)

Comment: Using the command 'gcloud builds submit' you can substitute parameters in the build specification: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--substitutions. Have a look at the documentation, and let me know if it's a valid option for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variables using Google Cloud Build or other method in Google App Engine Standard Environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840187/how-to-set-environment-variables-using-google-cloud-build-or-other-method-in-goo)

Answer (score 4):

[Using secrets from Secrets Manager](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets)

Your sample would become:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
  dir: "appengine/hello-world/standard"
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy", "test-app.yaml"]
  dir: "appengine/hello-world/standard"
  secretEnv: ['API_KEY', 'API_URL']

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/<secret name>/versions/latest
    env: API_KEY 
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/<secret name 2>/versions/latest
    env: API_URL
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [full tutorial](https://medium.com/@brian.young.pro/how-to-add-environmental-variables-to-google-app-engine-node-js-using-cloud-build-5ce31ee63d7) on how to securely store env vars in your cloud build (triggers) settings and import them into your app.

Basically there are three steps:

1. Add your env vars to the 'variables' section in one of your build trigger settings

   [Screenshot of where to add variables in build triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgRiE.png)

   By convention variables set in the build trigger must begin with an underscore (_)
2. Configure `cloudbuild.yaml` (on the second step in the code example) to read in variables from your build trigger, set them as env vars, and write all env vars in a local .env file

   Add `couldbuild.yaml` (below) to your project root directory

```js
steps:
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["install"]
- name: node:10.15.1
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["run", "create-env"]
  env:
    - 'MY_SECRET_KEY=${_MY_SECRET_KEY}'
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

Add `create-env` script to `package.json`

```js
"scripts": {
  "create-env": "printenv > .env"
},
```

3. Read env vars from .env to your app (config.js)

   Install dotenv package

   `npm i dotenv -S`

   Add a `config.js` to your app

```js
// Import all env vars from .env file
require('dotenv').config()

export const MY_SECRET_KEY = process.env.MY_SECRET_KEY

console.log(MY_SECRET_KEY) // => Hello
```

Done! Now you may deploy your app by triggering the cloud build and your app will have access to the env vars.

Comment: Whilst you're getting the variables into process.env if I'm not mistaken this solution would still create a new .env file, which a "bad admin" would still be able to get hold of and get the secrets as referenced in the initial post with the google storage option.

Comment: @TommyBs I guess the goal here is to store the secrets somewhere on GCP account and not in the code locally. So the secrets are only going to be as secure as your GCP login. However, I personally feel setting up google storage to store secrets and having to fetch them in your app is a lot more work.

Comment: @highfivebrian Is this still valid? I'm not able to create .env file from cloudbuild.yaml. It was working couple months ago for sure. Same code I'm trying to deploy and it is not creating .env file in app engine. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

**Add a cloud trigger step in your cloudbuild.yaml to add place holders in your app.yaml file**

```
    steps:
    - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
      secretEnv: ['API_KEY','API_URL']
      entrypoint: 'bash'   args: 
      - -c
      - |
        echo $'\n  API_KEY: '$$API_KEY >> app.yaml
        echo $'\n  API_URL: '$$API_URL >> app.yaml
        gcloud app deploy
    availableSecrets:   secretManager:
      - versionName: projects/012345678901/secrets/API_KEY
        env: 'API_KEY'
      - versionName: projects/012345678901/secrets/API_URL
        env: 'API_URL'
```

**look following reference app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs
service: serviceone
env_variables:
  PROJECT_ID: demo
  PORT: 8080
```

Reference by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13763858/cadet

Comment: **look following reference app.yaml** 
`runtime: nodejs
main: cmd
service: serviceone
env_variables:
  PROJECT_ID: demo
  PORT: 8080`