# Securely providing external service credentials to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm just getting started with Google App Engine, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to securely provide credentials for external services to a deployed app. I saw that you can put environment variables in the `app.yaml` config file, but I don't want to store secret credentials in plain text on my local machine, and I would like to store the deploy agnostic parts of the `app.yaml` in version control.

What are the best practices for providing Google App Engine with sensitive deploy specific variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good place to store configuration in Google AppEngine (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777367/what-is-a-good-place-to-store-configuration-in-google-appengine-python)

Comment: many questions already answer this, including much more recent one that i couldnt find quickly. google for "appengine store sensitive site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: Trust me, I googled a lot of things, just not the special magic words. I tried "appengine securely store credentials", and anything with "password" was just noise. Thanks for pointing me to the right place, and hopefully this page helps other people searching for "appengine credentials".